# Change the style of a footnote rule?

Tags: pdftex, footnotes

How can I change the style of my footnote from a simple line to something that has a gradient in colour, I mean from something like this :

[image]

To something like this (the colourful line should be a little bit shorter, it should ideally have the same length as the previous one) :

[image]

It doesn't really matter the colour as long as we will have a gradient in that specific colour

Comment: In standard classes, that line is drawn by `\footnoterule`, with a simple `\hrule`. Replacing that `\hrule` with some `tikz` axis-shading filled rectangle (`\fill[left color=..., right color=...] ...;`) will do the job. But since your "default" footnote style is different with the one in standard classes, in case your current setting has changed other footnote internals, knowing your current setting would be helpful.

Comment: But, this method can lead us to a long line, I want that line to be as shorter as the previous one Is there any command that can do this kind of line ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An example demonstrating what I suggested in [this comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/601422/change-the-style-of-a-footnote?noredirect=1#comment1508305_601422).

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
% old
% \def\footnoterule{\kern-3\p@
%   \hrule \@width 2in \kern 2.6\p@} % the \hrule is .4pt high

\def\footnoterule{%
  \kern-3\p@
  \hbox{%
    \tikz \fill[left color=blue!50!black, right color=white]
        (0,0) rectangle (2in,.4pt);%
  }%
  \kern 2.6\p@}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
text\footnote{\lipsum[2]}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks you so mush

Comment: I really appreciate it

Comment: Ops, the `[baseline=-.2pt]` is useless (and harmless too). I've removed it.